# least square minimisation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, least-squares, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit a curve in MATLAB to a data set I have and am trying to get a least squares minimisation. The curve is a convolution of a Gaussian and an exponential function so I've used a for loop, the curve has 5 variables.

```
clip = 8192;
marker=(1:8192);
ti=(1:8192);
counts=counts(1:8192);
sigma=125;
lambda=0.00028;
b=0.69;
a=8;
t0=850;
clear Z;


Z(1:clip,1:clip)=zeros;
marker1=marker;
marker1(1:t0)=0;
Z(ti,marker1);

for i=t0:clip;
    Z(:,i)=(exp(-lambda*ti(:))).*(exp(-(power((marker1(i)-ti(:)),2)/(2*sigma*sigma))));
end


est=sum(Z,2);

est=b*est+a;

%chi squared calculation:

delta = counts - est;
error = est.^(1/2);
u=(delta./error).^2;
chi2=sum(u);
chi2red=chi2/(8192-5-1)
```

Where counts is the only data that I input.

I'm having difficulty in finding a function to minimise this curve such that its variables (a, b, sigma, t0, lambda) give the best possible fit i.e the outputted 'est' (estimate) is as closely related to the input 'counts' as possible. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should add a line starting by function at its beginning.

Comment: Take a look at `fminsearch`, `lsqnonlin`, `mldivide`.

Comment: Also: could you modify the code snippet above, so that we can copy-paste and run it?